# Grouping with Filter Query Solr

Tags: solr

I had document in solr as mentioned below

Document 1

{
    "event_name":"product viewed",
    "event_property":["category","product_name","product_code","price","brand","color","discount","is_new_visitor"],
    "event_value":["category-sunglasses","product_name-david blake grey sunglasses","product_code-lcsgdb364x1880gryx""price-590","brand-david blake","color-grey","discount-70"],
    "session_id":"mf1545212054754888840",
    "company_id":"31",
    "created":1545212153,
    "email":"zzzz@gmail.com",
    "name":"zzzz"
}

Document 2

{
    "event_name":"add to cart",
    "event_property":["category","product_name","product_code","price","brand","color","discount","is_new_visitor"],
    "event_value":["category-sunglasses","product_name-david blake grey sunglasses","product_code-lcsgdb364x1880gryx""price-590","brand-david blake","color-grey","discount-70"],
    "session_id":"mf1545212054754888840",
    "company_id":"31",
    "created":1545212153,
    "email":"zzzz@gmail.com",
    "name":"zzzzz"
}

Document 3

{
    "event_name":"product viewed",
    "event_property":["category","product_name","product_code","price","brand","color","discount","is_new_visitor"],
    "event_value":["category-sunglasses","product_name-david blake grey sunglasses","product_code-lcsgdb364x1880gryx""price-590","brand-david blake","color-grey","discount-70"],
    "session_id":"mf1545212054754888841",
    "company_id":"31",
    "created":1545212153,
    "email":"yyyy@gmail.com",
    "name":"xxxxxx"
}
document have email and activity perform by user in event key.now i need to make request to group email to find unique email using filter query.i have used the query mentioned below

```
http://solr-url/solr/solr-core/select?q=*:*&fq=((event_name:"product+viewed"
+AND+event_property:"product_name"+AND+event_value:"category-sunglasses")+AND+(event_name:"add+to+cart"+AND+event_property:"product_name"+AND+event_value:"category-sunglasses"))&group.limit=1&group.ngroups=true&group=true&group.field=email
```

In response i am not getting the email e.g user who as performed both event e.g "product viewed" and "add to cart".

Comment: Your query is trying to retrieve all documents that have an `event_name` of both `product viewed` and `add to cart`. From your example document the document only has a single value in this field, so no documents will match your query (i.e. no documents will satisfy both the part before and after the `AND`. Are you trying to find out the unique emails of those who both viewed the product and then added it to their cart?

Comment: yes i am trying to find unique emails of those who both viewed the product and then added it to their cart,may you suggest a way to do so.

Comment: The [Streaming Expressions API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/streaming-expressions.html) was created to solve analytics problems like this, where your query is attempting to correlate data across multiple documents. In this case you'd probably create two queries and a join across them. Try it out and add a couple example documents to your post if you need more help

Comment: Is any other way to implement the same?

Comment: i had modified the original post added 3 documents to make question more clear.Now search can be classified in point 1 ,2 .point 1. i need to find all the email which has performed event_name "product viewed" and event_name "add to cart" 2. I need to find all email which has performed event_name "product viewed" and NOT performed "add to cart" also i need to group the email as each document in solr has email.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your query, the filter query should AND, should be OR.

fq=((event_name:"product+viewed"
+AND+event_property:"product_name"+AND+event_value:"category-sunglasses")+**OR**+(event_name:"add+to+cart"+AND+event_property:"product_name"+AND+event_value:"category-sunglasses"))

Comment: I need to select the user email who had performed both the event namely "product viewed" and "add to cart". if i will use or than i will not get the expected result

Comment: I'm not very clear about your requirement, but you can consider the join query : `q={!join from=email to=email}*:*`

Comment: i had modified the original post added 3 documents to make question more clear.Now search can be classified in point 1 ,2 .point 1. i need to find all the email which has performed event_name "product viewed" and event_name "add to cart" 2. I need to find all email which has performed event_name "product viewed" and NOT performed "add to cart" also i need to group the email as each document in solr has email.

Comment: try this `q={!join from=email to=email}event_name:"product+viewed"*&fq=event_name:"add+to+cart"`. See if works.